# forum module error

Tags: php, forum, silverstripe

I have installed a forum module for SS. I'm currently using version 2.3.3

After I installed the `forum` file on the back end I receive a message that says *“File not found”* on Firefox, and *“This webpage is not found”* on Google Chrome.

---

I followed all the instructions but I still get the error message.

Also, when I run `http://mysite.co.za/dev/build/?flush=1`, I receive this error message

```
>[User Error] 
Couldn't run query: 

CREATE TABLE `ForumCategory` ( 
    `ID` int(11) not null auto_increment, 
    `ClassName` enum('ForumCategory') character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci default 'ForumCategory', 
    `Created` datetime, 
    `LastEdited` datetime, 
    `Title` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, 
    `StackableOrder` varchar(2) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, 
    `ForumHolderID` int(11) not null default '0', 
     index `ForumHolderID` (ForumHolderID), 
     index `ClassName` (ClassName), primary key (ID) ) TYPE=MyISAM

     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 14

GET /dev/build/flush=1
Line 401 in /home/neutrog7/public_html/sapphire/core/model/MySQLDatabase.php"
```

Comment: What MySQL database version are you running. `TYPE` is deprecated and I believe has been removed in later versions. If you change it to `ENGINE` it should run. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47974 - Confirmed removed in 5.2

Comment: I'm running on:  version: 4.1.22

Comment: 2.3.3 is a *very* old version of SilverStripe. What version of the Forum module are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to upgrade to a newer version of SilverStripe.  I'd recommend upgrading to 3.0 if you can, but if it becomes too much effort to upgrade to 3.0 then try 2.4.

If you really can't upgrade at this stage, you'll need to replace "TYPE" with "ENGINE" in MySQLDatabase.php.  But, really, you're going to be mostly on your own if you go down this path and upgrading would be much better.